# Case Select for Javascript Dropdown

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, getelementbyid

So this is the first time I've tried Javascript.  I'm essentially trying to produce unique DIV's based on the value selected in a dropdown box.  I've got it to show the DIV's but the values don't change based on what is selected.  Here's what I've got so far:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JHjFL/2/)

As you can see, when the $200,000 range is select I want to produce fixed value's that I've already calculated.  I was curious to see if there was a switch or case select statement that I could somehow produce to change the DIV's based on the actual option selected on the dropdown.  Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should consider using jQuery. You can also do this in a few lines of code by using class names instead of individual IDs.

Comment: I have no idea how to even go about using jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use jQuery, you could try switching the select and setting the innerHTML of value1, value2, value3

```
    switch(document.getElementById('mySelect').value)
{
    case '0': 
        document.getElementById('value1').innerHTML ='Principal and Interest only: $898';
        document.getElementById('value2').innerHTML = 'Estimated total monthly payment: $1,098';
        document.getElementById('value3').innerHTML ='VA loan payment:';    
        break;   
    case '1': 
        document.getElementById('value1').innerHTML ='Principal and Interest only: $998';
        document.getElementById('value2').innerHTML = 'Estimated total monthly payment: $2,098';
        document.getElementById('value3').innerHTML ='VA loan payment: $25';    
        break;          
    etc...
}
```

Comment: Nice.  This is exactly what I was looking for Stuart.  I knew there was a way to get it to switch, but I didn't realize you would have to encapsulate the entire getelementbyid with the switch.  I appreciate your time and patience.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do this using jQuery:

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="showhide(this)">
    <option value="">Desired Home Price:</option>
    <!-- the option values are suffixes for the elements to show -->
    <option value="0">$200,000</option>
    <option value="1">$175,000</option>
    <option value="2">$150,000</option>
    <option value="3">$125,000</option>
    <option value="4">$100,000</option>
    <option value="5">$75,000</option>
    <option value="6">$50,000</option>
</select>

<div class="answer0 answers" style="width:200px;height:200px;display:none">
<div id="value1">Principal and Interest only: $898</div> 
<div id="value2">Estimated total monthly payment: $1,098</div>
<div id="value3">VA loan payment:</div>
<div id="value4">Another field:</div>
</div>

<div class="answer1 answers" style="width:200px;height:200px;display:none">
<div id="value1a">Principal and Interest only: $898.00</div> 
<div id="value2a">Estimated total monthly payment: $1,098.00</div>
<div id="value3a">VA loan payment:</div>
<div id="value4a">Another field:</div>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">

function showhide(id) {
    var mySel = $(id).val()
    $('.answers').hide()  
    $('.answer'+mySel).show()  
}

</script>
```

​

Comment: Thank you so much! This definitely loaded great in jsfiddle.  One more quick question, how do I invoke jQuery for the page?

Comment: You need to include it in your HEAD: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: In jsfiddle you can select jQuery on the left menu.

Comment: Ya I definitely saw the dropdown for jQuery on the side page of jsfiddle.  I just was unsure as to how to invoke it through my page on HTML.  Thanks for all the help/support Diodeus.

Comment: So when it comes down to implementing this code from jfiddle to dreamweaver, it does not load at all.  Anyone have any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/fc3BX/

Comment: Paste in in SOURCE mode, not preview mode.

Comment: Ya I'm definitely not pasting while it's in Live View.  I'm also pasting it on the source code side.  I've put the jQuery plugin code in the head.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong but I can't get it displayed. Here's the pastebin http://pastebin.com/Rbm13Lez

Comment: Turns out this is an issue somehow with Dreamweaver / Local viewing of Firefox.  Once uploaded to my server it works fine.  I wonder what is causing that issue?